# update mysql result (set to deleted) using ajax without page refresh?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have rows of data in a mysql table called user_timeline.

I have a column in this table labeled deleted.

I'm running my query to fetch all results in my table where deleted = 0.

```
$result = $conn ->query ("SELECT * FROM user_timeline WHERE user_id = '$p_id' AND deleted = '0' ORDER BY time_date DESC");
```

I want to give the user the option to be able to mark a result as deleted in the table by setting this to 1.

I figure i can do this by creating a link that will post to my page del_timeline.php

```
if(isset($_SESSION['CUSTOMER_ID'])){
    echo '<a id="del_t" href="assets/del_timeline.php?t_id='.$row['id'].'"><div class="delete_timeline"></div></a>';
    }
```

In del_timeline.php i have the following update query:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['t_id'])){
    $t_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['t_id']);
    $myID = $_SESSION['CUSTOMER_ID'];
    $conn->query("Update user_timeline Set deleted = '1' Where id = $t_id AND user_id = $myID") ;

}
?>
```

As you can imagine, each result in my table will have a specific/unique ID. So that it can keep track of which result the user is trying to set as deleted. Whilst this works via a normal href click event. I am trying to get this to run using ajax to avoid a page refresh.

I am not entirely sure how to pass a mysql $row parameter through ajax. I  have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script>
$( "#del_t" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault(); // <---- Add this line

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "assets/del_timeline.php?t_id=$row['id']",
        data: $( "#del_t" ).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            // print here 

        },
        dataType: 'html' // for json response or 'html' for html response
    });
    </script>
```

please can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Use data attributes to store the ID, and then in jQuery read the data-attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

You not need to add the id from php to ajax function. You can use the href address from the link.

```
$( "#del_t" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    data: '',
    success: function(data) {
        // print here 

    },
    dataType: 'html' // for json response or 'html' for html response
});
```

Or, better, put the id into an attribute in `<a>` (ex. in title), use $_REQUEST in php. In ajax get the id from that attribute to pass it in data sent via post. In php:

```
echo '<a id="del_t" href="assets/del_timeline.php?t_id='.$row['id'].'" title="'.$row['id'].'"><div class="delete_timeline"></div></a>';
```

In del_timeline.php:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['t_id'])){
  $t_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['t_id']);
  //your code
}
```

Ajax:

```
$( "#del_t" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'assets/del_timeline.php',
    data: 't_id='+$(this).attr('title'),
    success: function(data) {
        // print here 

  },
  dataType: 'html' // for json response or 'html' for html response
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to attach event handler to prevent page reload when users click on `href` links. Consider something like this in your javascript:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', 'a[id="del_t"]', function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: $( this ).attr( 'href' )
  } )
  .done( function( response ) {
    // Do something with the success response...
    // Maybe delete the row containing deleted data
  } );
} );
```

Then, you'll need to send some data from your `del_timeline.php`.
Use PHP's `echo` to pass mysql result or any PHP variable to the client browser (your javascript code).

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  include 'connect.php';

  if(isset($_GET['t_id'])){
    $t_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['t_id']);
    $myID = $_SESSION['CUSTOMER_ID'];
    $conn->query("Update user_timeline Set deleted = '1' Where id = $t_id AND user_id = $myID") ;

    // Send some success response
    echo 'success'; // or any data you want to send
  }

  // Send some error response
  echo 'error';
?>
```